# How does CartThrob limit coupon code usage?

Tags: cartthrob, coupon-code

When you set up a coupon code, you can specify how many times it can be used per customer (via the "Per User Limit" field). However, how does CartThrob keep track of this? I assume by member ID, if the user is logged in. But what if they're not logged in? Is it by IP address, by the billing/shipping info they enter for their order, or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, CartThrob can only use this feature for logged-in members. It cannot track coupon code usage by guests.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks for the quick response.